# How to Select all the cells in a worksheet in Excel.Range object of c#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to select all the cells in an Excel sheet in the `Excel.Range` object of C# for applying auto fit, border etc. I have some merged cells within the sheets.

Is there any simple trick to do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291308), this will select all cells in the worksheet:

```
lastCol = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Column
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(65536, lastCol).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("a1", ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select
```

Answer (score 17):

```
Excel.Range theRange = (Excel.Range)CurrentSheet.UsedRange;
```

In this example, CurrentSheet is the variable where you have stored the sheet you are currently using.

Comment: Although the OP actually asked for "all cells", this is what I, and I suspect most other users were actually looking for.

Answer (score 14):

```
public void refreshSheetColumsSize(Worksheet ws)
 {
    ws.get_Range("a1").EntireRow.EntireColumn.Select();         
 }
```

Comment: Looks nice, but i got this exception `Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'`

Comment: get_range should return a range and not a bool : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.get_range.aspx call ws.get_Range("a1"); in a separate row and debug the result.

Comment: removing the `Select()`will do it. I was getting the same exception as Yola. I mean, create a method that returns a `Range`and return `get_Range("a1").EntireRow.EntireColumn`

Answer (score 3):

Officially, Excel.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows and Excel.Worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.

In practice, it's buggy, you have to subtract the start row and column. The closest-to-correct answer is:

```
   Public ReadOnly Property LastColumn() As Integer
        Get
            Return ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count + _
                   ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange.Column - 1
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property LastRow() As Integer
        Get
            Return ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + _
                   ExcelWorksheet.UsedRange.Row - 1
        End Get
    End Property
```

This returns *at least* all the used cells, sometimes a little more. The 'little more' can be due to blank cells (rather than empty), and other random things. Form the research I did, this is the best that can be done.

If you really want to select **everything** then

```
ExcelWorksheet.Activate()
ExcelWorksheet.Cells.Select()
```

Answer (score 2):

I've not done any excel development for a while (Excel 2003) but I always found that recording a macro while performing the tasks I was wanting to implement in code have sufficient pointers to help.

In this case, selecting all cells and autofitting gives the code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

which I would imagine would roughly translate to:

```
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)_sheet.Cells.Select()).AutoFit();
```

where _sheet is the instance of the Worksheet you're using. 
(untested)

Answer (score 2):

To consider all cells of a worksheet you can write like:

```
workSheet.Cells[workSheet.Rows.Count,workSheet.Columns.Count]
```

OR

```
 workSheet.get_Range("A1","IV65536")
```

To consider used cells of a worksheet, you can write:

```
workSheet.Rows.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, XlSpecialCellsValue.xlTextValues)
```

Where "worksheet" represents the sheet you are working on. Both code sample returns a range.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Much cleaner and doesn't depend on the number of rows/cols which were increased in Excel 2007:

Provided your sheet is in a variable called wsData:

```
wsData.Range(wsData.Cells(1, 1), wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, wsData.Columns.Count))
```

Comment: For me wsData.Rows.Count always return 65536 instead of used rows FYI

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Select()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
worksheet.Columns.AutoFit()
```

Where "worksheet" is a variable of type [Worksheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
        xlWorksheet.get_Range("a1").EntireRow.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
        xlWorksheet.get_Range("a1").EntireColumn.EntireRow.AutoFit();
```

After cell filling has been finished.