# c# generated excel sheet with chart template

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, api, npoi

Good afternoon,

I have a .net API that will receive a request from the client to generate an excel sheet. So far, so good. I receive the request, query the database, get the data, and write it to a sheet in an excel workbook.

It's actually the excel part I'm struggling with. I want to have a pre-made excel sheet with charts referring to a table that doesn't exist yet. It's this table that will be written upon request. I do not know in advance how many rows there will be, so this must adjust dynamically. I can't seem to figure out how to create a chart and have it point to data that doesn't exist yet.

For a simple example the c# program will write the following:

```
Car Brand | Total
Honda      12
Dodge      24
BMW        6
```

This will be written on a second sheet, and on the first sheet is a bar chart that will now nicely display this data. The intention is after the c# program writes the data, I can then close the stream, and return the excel sheet to the client. When they view it on their end, the first sheet will have a populated chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am more used to VBA, but I think what you are looking for is explained here :

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-chart.htm

After the code generates an Excel worksheet, it adds some data, then create a chart object by retrieving the data in a hard coded way. If you know where you start to copy the values on your second page, and that the data is contiguous, then you may use [range.end](/questions/tagged/range.end) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850738/how-to-select-all-the-cells-in-a-worksheet-in-excel-range-object-of-c) to get to the end, and throw this in your chart, located in the first sheet. So the chart would not be waiting to point to a dynamically created list, but rather created after the list is being populated (pre-made, but in your code). If it is a matter of one column of strings and one column of numbers, I think that this method may be convenient.

Comment: Thank you. I see though that you are creating the chart programatically. This looks like it will work well, but I was hoping to be able to have designed the excel sheet before, and would only be missing the data.

This way I can design a nice spreadsheet and have the charts be populated by data.

I really just want to be able to have a chart that points to, say: all rows in column A and B on sheet "data". The x axis being all rows in col A and the y axis col B, for example...

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your data : https://trumpexcel.com/dynamic-chart-range/

Comment: It seems so obvious now that I read that link. I think I had made this to be much more complicated than it needed to be.

It works now. I have created a table with just one row of data so that at least it exists. A chart, on another sheet, now points to that table. My c# program writes to the sheet with the table and voila! The chart is dynamically produced.

Thank you very much!